# How can I easily backup data from external card on Android 4.0.4 to a new external card?

Tags: external-sd, system-apps

I intend to buy a new external card of larger capacity for Android 4.0.4 phone and would like to backup and restore data from currently installed external card to a new card so I can restore the data and apps on the new phone. Is there a cloud backup and restore!? Easy Backup app or other solution?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to transfer the files to a computer, then transfer them from the computer to your new card. Many micro (phone size) sd cards come with a micro to regular size adapter that will fit in the card reader slots of most computers.

Comment: That is the easiest. +1